# limits of partial sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

how do i even start?

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence. Assume that the only subsequent limits of $a_n$ are $\pm1$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=1$.

Comment: What's a "partial limit"? Does that mean, limit of some subsequence?

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't know the word in english.
what i meant is that the only subsequent limits are +-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\cdot|$ is continuous, $\liminf a_n=-1$ and $\limsup a_n=1$ ($a_n$ is bounded) we have
$$1=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|$$
and
$$1=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|.$$
Therefore $\lim |a_n|=1$.

Comment: thank you very much.
what do you mean by "continuous"? i know this term about functions but not about sequences.

Comment: $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a continuous function, therefore you can interchange limits of sequences , i.e. if $\lim b_n=b$, then $\lim|b_n|=|\lim b_n|=|b|$.